# I am getting a error while loading a font in react native using expo

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo, custom-font

[image]
This is the error I am getting while I am loading the font. It works fine on most of the screen but the app crashes in some specific screens.

Comment: You should load all asset as the error point out, refer here https://docs.expo.io/versions/v29.0.0/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, I just had to use the await function. I am not deleting my query as If someone else faces the same issue they can still refer to this.

This is my answer :

```
 await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
      'avenir_light': require('../Assets/fonts/avenir_light.otf'),
      'avenir-bold': require('../Assets/fonts/avenir_bold.otf'),
      'avenir-medium': require('../Assets/fonts/avenir_medium.otf'),
    });
    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
```